# How to add a custom URL scheme programmatically on macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, custom-protocol

I need to create a URL scheme that will allow me to open a file with its default software.

For this, I have an .app file that contains the function to open a file via a sent parameter:

```
myCustomProtocol://Users/xxx/indesign/A.indd
```

So I managed to make it work by doing everything manually via: https://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001154

I would now like to automate this URL scheme creation via a script (for the moment, I use SwiftDefaultApps: https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps).

[image]

The .app file will be provided to the user but I must be able to install the custom protocol when installing an application.

Here I have to create a URL scheme programmatically that runs this .app file (like this example with Zoom).

[image]

I did my research before making this post but did not find any clear answers.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: why is there a `C:` in an URL for macOS?

Comment: My bad.. This is a bad example, I'm editing this right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just launch the .app file manually and restart the Mac (?) to register the url scheme in macos.

I can then call my custom protocol.

Source: https://github.com/chrisliuqq/mac-custom-url-scheme-to-script